Starting a Postgres TestContainer inside a Gradle task
I am learning Gradle and I am trying to do the following:

Inside a Gradle task, start a postgres testcontainer with a sql init script.
Use Jooq codegen to generate sources from this database.

Currently, I am just working on point 1. I try to start a postgres container in a task:
abstract class StartDbContainer : DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun startContainer() {
        PostgreSQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:17.0")).apply {
            withUsername("user")
            withPassword("password")
            withDatabaseName("test")
            withInitScript("schema.sql")
            start()
        }
    }
    
}

I then add the schema.sql to the buildscript classpath as such:
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        // <some other dependencies>
        classpath(files("src/main/resources/schema.sql"))
    }

}

However, executing this task fails: org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$ScriptLoadException: Could not load classpath init script: schema.sql. Resource not found.
I tried changing withInitScript("schema.sql") to withInitScript(""src/main/resources/schema.sql") but this also does not work.
Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Do I have a misunderstanding of how the gradle buildscript classpath works or is testcontainers just not built to do this?

Docker postgres containers have this property that you also mount the init script at /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, which will be executed on startup.
Therefore, we can make this work as follows as described here:
val schemaPath = layout.projectDirectory.file("src/main/resources/schema.sql").asFile.path

val container = PostgreSQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres:17.0")).apply {
    withCopyToContainer(MountableFile.forHostPath(schemaPath), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql")
    start()
}

